# How can I change the distance function in Classify when using NearestNeighbor?

Tags: cluster-analysis, machine-learning

**Issue not present in version `"10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"`**

---

```
trainingset = {"A" -> 1, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 6};
classifier = 
 Classify[trainingset, 
  Method -> {"NearestNeighbors", "NeighborsNumber" -> 5, 
    "DistanceFunction" -> CosineDistance}]
```

I'm getting the message

> Unknown option "DistanceFunction" in Classify

However, when I evaluate

```
ClassifierInformation[classifier, "Properties"]
```

I see `"DistanceFunction"` in the list of properties returned.

I see the same thing in the OpenCV toolbox. In `KnearestNeighbors` function, I can not change the `DistanceFunction` despite Euclidean distance not being the best choice, specially with big data.

Comment: It seems that is a bug in the Classify function